# How to switch connected device in AirPods Pro without disabling bluetooth from the original device

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, airpods

Is there an easier way to switch between paired devices while using AirPods Pro? I have iPhone and MacBook (on phone I am using personal Apple account and on work computer I have work account). Issue comes when I first connect AirPods to MacBook or iPhone and after a while I would like to switch the device. Only solution I found now is that I need to disconnect AirPods from MacBook or iPhone (via bluetooth), before I can switch device. Even when MacBook is in sleep mode and I can't connect my iPhone to AirPods. Instead I need to grab my laptop from backpack, login and disconnect them from bluetooth which is inconvenient when you are on the go.

I checked this support page, but I don't see an option to switch device on my iPhone: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212204
Has this something to do with different Apple account? Also this doesn't solve the issue when I would want iPhone to take over of MacBook without logging in to the MacBook.

Comment: For me it works like in the Apple article you link. You need to be logged into the same Apple account on your iPhone and Mac. My AirPods first link to my iPhone, but when I play, say a movie on the Mac, they'll transfer to the Mac. It doesn't always work straight away and I often employ the manual switching described in the Apple support article. Have you tried factory resetting the AirPods: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT209463

Comment: Thanks Ole, I will try with the same account if that would solve the issue

Comment: Tried with the same Apple account and still unable to switch device when airpods are connected to either macbook or iphone. Only manually disconnecting it via bluetooth does the trick. Tried to do the factory reset, still same issue.

Comment: Sorry, to leave you dry on this issue. I'm not in here very often. Someone in my team had the same issue and we found that since he was using different Apple IDs on his personal and work devices, this feature isn't available in his scenario. So unfortunately, this won't work.